# How to break a foreach loop in laravel blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I have a loop like this:

```
@foreach($data as $d)
    @if(condition==true)
        {{$d}}
        // Here I want to break the loop in above condition true.
    @endif
@endforeach
```

I want to break the loop after data display if condition is satisfied.

How it can be achieved in laravel blade view ?

Comment: Use `@break` before `@endif`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

From the [Blade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops):

> When using loops you may also end the loop or skip the current
>   iteration:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($user->type == 1)
        @continue
    @endif

    <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>

    @if ($user->number == 5)
        @break
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: @break will work similar to other usage of break in loops ?

Answer (score 6):

you can break like this

```php
@foreach($data as $d)
    @if($d === "something")
        {{$d}}
        @if(condition)
            @break
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 5):

> Basic usage

By default, blade doesn't have `@break` and `@continue` which are useful to have. So that's included.

Furthermore, the `$loop` variable is introduced inside loops, (almost) exactly like Twig.

> Basic Example

```
@foreach($stuff as $key => $val)
     $loop->index;       // int, zero based
     $loop->index1;      // int, starts at 1
     $loop->revindex;    // int
     $loop->revindex1;   // int
     $loop->first;       // bool
     $loop->last;        // bool
     $loop->even;        // bool
     $loop->odd;         // bool
     $loop->length;      // int

    @foreach($other as $name => $age)
        $loop->parent->odd;
        @foreach($friends as $foo => $bar)
            $loop->parent->index;
            $loop->parent->parentLoop->index;
        @endforeach
    @endforeach 

    @break

    @continue

@endforeach
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for `$loop->last;`

Comment: @YasserCHENIK Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Official docs say: *When using loops you may also end the loop or skip the current iteration using the **@continue** and **@break** directives:*

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
@if ($user->type == 1)
    @continue
@endif

<li>{{ $user->name }}</li>

@if ($user->number == 5)
    @break
@endif
```

@endforeach

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me

```
@foreach(config('app.languages') as $lang)
    @continue(app()->getLocale() === $lang['code'])
    <div class="col">
       <a href="#" class="btn w-100">
          {!! $lang['img'] !!}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $lang['name'] }}
       </a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($data as $d)
    @if(condition==true)
        {{$d}}
        @break // Put this here
    @endif
@endforeach
```