# Is there any function to stop foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm setting up a loop whenever i tried to print table first row print good with category name and then next row print table with ONE tr(row) data and closed the tag and again start new row and print next data with one row...

i want to print all data with respect to its category name without break multiple table

```
@if( ! empty($packages) )
    @php
        $serviceId=null;
    @endphp
    @foreach($packages as $package)
        @if(is_null($serviceId))
        <!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
        <div class="row" id="">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well wellHeader">
              <h2>{{ $package->service->name }}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
        @php
            $serviceId=$package->service->id
        @endphp

        @endif

        @if($serviceId != $package->service_id)
        <!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
        <div class="row" id="">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well wellHeader">
              <h2>{{ $package->service->name }}</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
        @php
            $serviceId = $package->service_id
        @endphp
        @endif

    <!--SERVICE NAME TABLE-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="well">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-sm ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>@lang('general.package_id')</th>
                              <th>@lang('general.name')</th>
                              <th>@lang('general.price_per_item') {{ getOption('display_price_per') }}</th>
                              <th>@lang('general.minimum_quantity')</th>
                              <th>@lang('general.maximum_quantity')</th>
                              <th>@lang('general.description')</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td>{{ $package->id }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $package->name }}</td>
                              <td>@php $price = isset($userPackagePrices[$package->id]) ? $userPackagePrices[$package->id] : $package->price_per_item;
@endphp
{{ getOption('currency_symbol') . number_formats(($price * getOption('display_price_per')),2, getOption('currency_separator'), '') }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $package->minimum_quantity }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $package->maximum_quantity }}</td>
                              <td>{{ $package->description }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    !--SERVICE NAME TABLE-->
    @endforeach

    @else
    No Record Found
    @endif
```

[image]

Comment: Wait, this isn't about JavaScript...why did you tag it when it's not relevant?

Comment: my table is break into multiple check screenshot

Comment: See [`break`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) and possibly [`continue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189524/how-to-break-a-foreach-loop-in-laravel-blade-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extra array to map this,

In method

```
$packagesNew = [];
foreach($packages as $k => $v)
{
  $packagesNew[$v->service->name]['name'] = $v->service->name;
  $packagesNew[$v->service->name]['id'] = $v->service->id;
  $packagesNew[$v->service->name]['service_id'] = $v->service_id;
  $packagesNew[$v->service->name]['data'][] = $v;
}
```

pass `packagesNew` to view

Then I made changes in view, please check.

```
@if( ! empty($packagesNew) )
@php
$serviceId=null;
@endphp
@foreach($packagesNew as $k => $package)
@if(is_null($serviceId))
<!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
<div class="row" id="">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well wellHeader">
            <h2>{{ $k }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
@php
$serviceId=$package['id'];
@endphp
@endif
@if($serviceId != $package['service_id'])
<!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
<div class="row" id="">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well wellHeader">
            <h2>{{ $k }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--CATEGORY NAME PRINT-->
@php
$serviceId = $package['service_id'];
@endphp
@endif
<!--SERVICE NAME TABLE-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="well">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-sm ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>@lang('general.package_id')</th>
                            <th>@lang('general.name')</th>
                            <th>@lang('general.price_per_item') {{ getOption('display_price_per') }}</th>
                            <th>@lang('general.minimum_quantity')</th>
                            <th>@lang('general.maximum_quantity')</th>
                            <th>@lang('general.description')</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($package['data'] as $k1 => $v1)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $v1->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $v1->name }}</td>
                            <td>@php $price = isset($userPackagePrices[$v1->id]) ? $userPackagePrices[$v1->id] : $v1->price_per_item;
                                @endphp
                                {{ getOption('currency_symbol') . number_formats(($price * getOption('display_price_per')),2, getOption('currency_separator'), '') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $v1->minimum_quantity }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $v1->maximum_quantity }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $v1->description }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
!--SERVICE NAME TABLE-->
@endforeach
@else
No Record Found
@endif
```

Comment: did you mean create this method in model ?

Comment: May be you are creating packages in model or controller, you know. There you need to write this code

Comment: code in models and controller is encrypted with ioncube :\ is there any way ?

Comment: Try writing somewhere you feel ;)

Comment: ok lemme try :)

Comment: @EpycDev Does my answer solves your problem?